# Delay between email using queue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, queue

The situation is I upload .csv that contains 50 emails, for example. How I can delay between 2 emails send because the mailtrap free package just allowed sending rate limit per 10 seconds just 2 emails. So I need to delay within 10 second. This what I has tried, but the email still send in batch.

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

        $participant = new Participant();
        $participant->p_name = $participantArray[0][$i]['name'];
        $participant->p_email = $participantArray[0][$i]['email'];
        $participant->p_address = $participantArray[0][$i]['address'];
        $participant->p_postcode = $participantArray[0][$i]['postcode'];
        $participant->p_city = $participantArray[0][$i]['city'];
        $participant->p_state = $participantArray[0][$i]['state'];
        $participant->p_contact = $participantArray[0][$i]['contactno'];
        $confirmation_code = str_random(30);
        $participant->confirmation_code = $confirmation_code;
        $participant->save();
        $participant->campaign()->attach($request->campaign_id);

        $details = [
            'email' => $participantArray[0][$i]['email'],
            'confirmation_code' => $confirmation_code
        ];

        $emailJob = (new SendEmail($details))->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(10));
        dispatch($emailJob);
    }
```

Comment: What driver are you using for the Queue Jobs?

Comment: I don't know if you can use debugmail instead of mailtrap :) I am not sure if debugmail has the same limit.

Comment: Try creating the initial carbon instance outside of the loop and then just add 10 seconds to that each time.

Comment: @EnriqueChavez i use QUEUE_DRIVER=database

Comment: @sochas thanks for sugeestion

Comment: @Rwd i will try it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be to create the carbon instance outside of the loop and then keep adding to that. Currently, you're telling Laravel to delay the job by 10 seconds from the time of each iteration but there will (more than likely) less than 1ms between each iteration so the jobs are still going to be processed around the same time.

```
$now = now();

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

    //The rest of your code

    dispatch(new SendEmail($details))->delay($now->addSeconds(10));
}
```

The above will mean that it will keep adding 10 seconds to the previous time. If you would like the first job to start straight away (and then delay each subsequent one by 10 seconds) then you could add to the carbon instance after you've set the delay on the job:

```
$now = now();

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

    //The rest of your code

    dispatch(new SendEmail($details))->delay($now);

    $now->addSeconds(10);
}
```

Comment: i got error "Unknown getter 'date'".I try solved it first

Comment: @HafizJamil What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @HafizJamil I've updated my answer. Let me know if you're still having issues with it.

Comment: thank a lot. I have tried the second solution and its work. It saves me time because I have tried 3 days to solve it. FYI, I still new to this framework. thanks again

Comment: @HafizJamil Glad I could help! :)